# Скрытие блоков

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Есть блок с рекламой. Как сделать, чтобы после нажатия пользователем на банер блок убирался  на день (не на 24 часа)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставите кукис 'не_показывать_баннер' и срок протухания - сколько надо.

Comment: А другой есть способ, не трогая кукис?

Comment: В бд заносить инфу, но нафик этот гемор... Куки рулят!